# Angular 8/7/6 Errors

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and learning angular 8/7/6.

I download a angular project from Bitbuckit and run the following command to install packages

```
npm install
```

then I run ng serve command and after that following error occures and failed to compile:

> ERROR in `node_modules/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators/services/form-control.d.ts`(1,54): error TS2305: Module '"`E:/webapp/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms`"' has no exported member 'AbstractControlOptions'.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the import of **AbstractControlOptions** and change it to **@angular/forms** instead of **@angular/forms/forms**

Or search for **@angular/forms/forms** directly

Comment: AbstractControlOptions is not found

Comment: and @angular/forms/forms?

Comment: file which has line import {AbstractControlOptions} from "@angular/forms/forms" is not found.

Comment: aha wait it is a problem in the dependency @rxweb/reactive-form-validators try updating it

Comment: AbstractControlOptions  already imported from  @angular/forms